# XSD Generation of a runtime object

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I am trying to generate a C# class based on an .xsd schema.  This schema has several imports which I included on the command line in my batch file.  It also has includes that should be resolved by using the schemaLocation to find the file on the disk.  I am getting errors for several types that are supposedly not declared.  These definitions are in the "included" schemas in a folder beneath the schema where the value is used.

Comment: Please post what you using to generate the C# classes (xsd.exe for example) and the exact error you are getting when executing.

Comment: xsd.exe - Schema validation warning: Type ' .... ' is not declared

The declaration is in a schema that is included in the schema where the error occurs (not imported, so the schema isn't explicitly listed).

I need to generate a C# class and then utilize it in my service to deserialize incoming xml strings.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the included schemas, XSD.EXE handles this fairly well, but you have to dig to find the documentation.

Look at [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s.aspx) in the poriton about using an XML file to direct XSD.EXE.  The short version is that you'll create a small xml file with multiple `<Schema>` nodes which point to: the schema for which you actually need schemas AND the imported schemas.

Then you'll run `XSD.EXE /p [yourXsdFile.xsd]`.  If you've follwed the instructions correctly (I've only done it once, so I'm no expert, and it took me a couple of tries to get the results I wanted) you'll get a single .cs file with all the necessary class data.

Comment: I've seen an implementation of using the XML file and this saves you from listing every referenced schema on the command line and this is for imports.  My problem is that I have an include that then includes 10 other schemas.  These can't be explicitly listed b/c they're all essentially in the same namespace.  However, the xsd.exe doesn't resolve the path and utilize the schemas.